# Why is there a NodeJS.ReadableStream interface in TypeScript?

Tags: node.js, typescript, typescript-typings

Wouldn't an object that satisfies the `NodeJS.ReadableStream` interface always inherit from `Readable`?

Comment: Seems like there's two questions in this post...

Comment: @vr. They are the same question, because `Readable` can replace `NodeJS.ReadableStream`.

Comment: No, the title asks "why" there is a ReadableStream interface, and the post body asks an entirely different question. Can you edit the post to be more clear about what you want to ask?

Comment: @vr. If you do not understand the question, you do not need to force yourself to comment.

Comment: From the `d.ts` files they look pretty different. 
I see `class Readable extends Stream implements NodeJS.ReadableStream`. And `Readable` has properties like `destroyed` that doesn't exist in a plain `ReadableStream`.

Comment: And TypeScript can tell me `Type 'ReadableStream' is missing the following properties from type 'Readable': readableAborted, readableDidRead, readableEncoding, readableEnded, and 11 more.`

Comment: There is also an `interface ReadWriteStream extends ReadableStream, WritableStream` there, but the strange thing is that `Duplex` doesn't use it.

Comment: Maybe these interfaces exist only for cross-version support?

Comment: In `class Duplex extends Readable implements Writable`, Readable implements NodeJS.ReadableStream and Writable implements NodeJS.WritableStream. So Duplex satisfies both NodeJS.ReadableStream and NodeJS.WritableStream. And
since `interface ReadWriteStream extends ReadableStream, WritableStream { }` adds no new properties, Duplex will satisfy ReadWriteStream as well (no missing properties).